Pasar delete a expresion lambda
**Buenos dias
Estoy aprendiendo linq, quisiera transformar un delete sql a una instruccion linq
este es el query (delete, no manejan llaves foraneas y no aplicaria un borrado en cascada)**
DELETE  wsIntOperLogResultado from wsIntOperLogResultado A
INNER JOIN wsIntOperSolServicio B ON A.IdSolicitud=B.Id WHERE Fecha  < '2024-03-08 00:20:13.280'
Estas dos son las entidades, cono se podria armar una sentencia linq para este delete?
[Table("wsIntOperLogResultado")]
        public class ResServicioDto
        {
            [Key]
            public Int64 Id { get; set; }
            public Int64 IdSolicitud { get; set; }
            public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
            public string TramaRecibida { get; set; }
            public string Respuesta { get; set; }
            public int Estado { get; set; }

        }


[Table("wsIntOperSolServicio")]
public class SolServicioDto
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public int Api { get; set; }
    public string Servicio { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaHora { get; set; }
    public string Parametros { get; set; }
    public int NroIntentos { get; set; }
    public string Usuario { get; set; }
    public int Estado { get; set; }

}


La instrucción DELETE que tú has puesto no se en que motor funciona, pero estoy seguro de que no lo hace en todos, pero esto lo controlará EF y para eso puedes usar la función ExecuteDelete
(from a in DB.ResServicioDto
 join b in DB.SolServicioDto on a.IdSolicitud equals b.Id
 where a.Fecha< Convert.ToDateTime("2024-03-08 00:20:13.280")
 select a).ExecuteDelete();

Entity Framework lo que convertirá esa expresión en SQL, pero está conversión varía según la librería que estes utilizando y el motor de base de datos.
Por ejemplo, utilizando SQLite quedará:
DELETE FROM "wsIntOperLogResultado" AS "w"
WHERE "w"."Id" IN (
   SELECT "w0"."Id"
   FROM "wsIntOperLogResultado" AS "w0"
   INNER JOIN "wsIntOperSolServicio" AS "w1" ON "w0"."IdSolicitud" = "w1"."Id"
   WHERE "w0"."Fecha" < '2024-03-08 00:20:13.28'
)


Otra forma de borrar más "clásica":
var result = from a in DB.ResServicioDto
 join b in DB.SolServicioDto on a.IdSolicitud equals b.Id
 where a.Fecha< Convert.ToDateTime("2024-03-08 00:20:13.280")
 select a;

DB.ResServicioDto.RemoveRange(result);
DB.SaveChanges();


No funciono, no expone el ExecuteDelete que libreria se necesita para verlo?

@JavierRocha La trae Entity Framework, me parece que desde la versión 7
